# How to call a function from a button in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have manipulated the List view in my Django Admin and set a button for each entry. Now, when I click on the button, I want a URL to be called from the server. In this URL, headers and parameters are to be transferred. One parameter is the field `pn` of the entry.

How can I do that? So far I have only the buttons without function.

```py
def button(self, obj):

return format_html("<button> Action </buttton>")
```

Comment: You can go two routes. **#1** make the button a link and just make it look like a button, click link -> get URL. **#2** Customize the template and add Javascript/Jquery to do an Ajax Post/Get on that button click.

Comment: @Nealium are this my options? A python method with requests is not possible?

Comment: Yeeepppp! You've got to think of it as two distinct things: The back end / Server (which is Python/Django) and the front end / Client (which is **only** HTML/CSS/Javascript) ..There's a very very firm wall between the two (The Client **cannot** Run Python) and the only way the front end can communicate with the back end is using HTTP requests (ex, Links or Ajax) - but that's the game: You poke/ping the Server have have it do complex things

Comment: As I mentioned it would be better if the requests comes from the server (back end - python)

Comment: You've got to initiate the transaction from the front end tho, else the server wouldn't know when or who to send it to. Flow: Button Click on Client -> Client Sends HTTP Request to Server -> Server Replies with Payload -> Client Handles Payload. To send that HTTP Request you've got to either do a Link or an Ajax Request.
So a link example would look like: `return format_html("<a class='csstomakelinkabutton' href='/your/url/here/'>Btn</a>")` try that, play around with it, if you don't like how to behaves try doing Javascript.